# Matlab GUI :: How to set the scroll to end of contents of the 'static text' screen

Tags: matlab, user-interface, scroll, reverse

Usually when messages are loaded to static text, scroll appear to top of the messages. One needs to scroll down to look at all the messages.

Is there a way in which one can reset/set GUI properties so that one has to scroll up to look at the messages ?

Comment: You mean you want to display the text so that we read it from bottom to top?

Comment: display remains unchanged but the scroll is already in fully scrolled down position intially, after that the user can scroll up. Just the initial settings

Comment: Any updates on this query ?

Comment: I'm afraid not; I could find a way to do it for static text boxes sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the trick was to set "VALUE" parameter to length of the string in the output screen.

So, I used LISTBOX to display the STATIC TEXT with style-->listbox,Value--> 1 using  ML GUIDE and then use the code in the script to change the VALUE parameter of the handles.

code : **set(handles.TAG, 'Value', length(sTringToDisplay));
       set(handles.TAG,'String',sTringToDisplay );
       pause(1);**

Hence the output screen will always point to the recent messages.